# Jackson with Spring boot: control object substitution for specific method

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have entity type as item in recursive tree, so any item has references to its parent and children (of same type)

```
public class Category {
  private Integer id;
  private String displayName;

  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
  private Category parent;

  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
  private Set<Category> children;

  // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

As you can see, I marked both reference fields with `@JsonIdentityReference` annotation forcing them to render as plain ids. Currently with this setup an entity is rendered as follows:

```
// from .../categories/0
{
  "id" : 0,
  "displayName" : "Root",
  "parent" : null,
  "children" : [ 1, 13, 17 ]
}
```

(which is perfectly fine).

However, very common use scenario for client is to fetch whole sub-tree starting from specific node, which in this implementation requires several requests to server. I want to create another enpoint that allows client to perform this operation with single request.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/categories")
public class CategoryController {
  @Autowired
  private CategoryService categoryService;
  @Autowired
  private CategoryRepository categoryRepo;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/tree", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Category getTree(@RequestParam(name = "root", required = false) Integer id) {
    Category root = id == null ? categoryService.getRoot() : categoryRepo.findOne(id);
    return categoryService.getTree(root);
  }

  // other endpoints
  // getOne(id)
  // getAll()
}
```

Response from this endpoint renders full objects only if I manually remove `(alwaysAsId=true)` flag from the `children` field. However, I want both endpoints coexist and render different layout. So, the question is: **How can I make specific controller method choose whether full entities are replaced with ids?**.

---

I already tried various combinations with `@JsonView`, but it seems this approach doesn't work. `@JsonView` can only control whether specific field is included or completely omitted, whereas I need `children` field to only change layout. Also, since child type is same as entity type, there is no way to split annotation marks between different classes.

Comment: I know I've filed a feature request about this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution. It is based on first version of Antot's answer and uses custom serializer for *content* of `children` collection. The tree producing endpoint is marked with `@JsonView(Category.TreeView.class)` annotation and unmarked field inclusion is turned ON

```
#application.properties
spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true
```

---

```
// Category.java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonSerialize(contentUsing = CategoryChildSerializer.class)
private Set<Category> children;
```

---

```
// CategoryChildSerializer.java
public class CategoryChildSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Category> implements ResolvableSerializer {
  private JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer;
  private JsonSerializer<Object> idSerializer;

  public void serialize(Category value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if(provider.getActiveView() == Category.TreeView.class)
      defaultSerializer.serialize(value, gen, provider);
    else
      idSerializer.serialize(value.getId(), gen, provider);
  }

  public void resolve(SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException {
    defaultSerializer = provider.findValueSerializer(Category.class);
    idSerializer = provider.findValueSerializer(Integer.class);
  }
}
```

Note how switching serializer delegates serialization instead of directly using `JsonGenerator`. Implementing `ResolvableSerializer` is in fact optional, it's just optimization step.

Answer (score 1):

/* *Updated answer, after the remark about loosing the view markers in multiple levels hierarchies.* */

The result you are looking for can still be achieved by using `@JsonView`s and a minor work-around inside `Category` object.

Supposing we have two types used as markers to output JSON views `FlatView` and `HierarchicalView`.

The principle of the solution is:

- we associate most of the fields with the views. `children` field remains associated with `FlatView` only.
- we create an additional getter for the `children` field, providing it with another property name, not clashing with the field or its original getter. This property is associated with `HierarchicalView` only.

It gives the following layout for `Category` class:

```
public class Category {

  @JsonView({ FlatView.class, HierarchicalView.class}) // both views
  private Integer id;

  @JsonView({ FlatView.class, HierarchicalView.class}) // both views
  private String displayName;

  @JsonView({ FlatView.class, HierarchicalView.class}) // both views
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  private Category parent;

  @JsonView(FlatView.class) // flat view only!
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  private Set<Category> children;

  @JsonView(HierarchicalView.class) // hierarchical view only!
  // note that the name is not `getChildren`: this generates another JSON property. 
  // Or use @JsonProperty to customize it.
  public Set<Category> getChildrenAsTree() { 
    return this.children;
  }

  // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

The controller methods producing the output should be annotated with respective `@JsonView`s.

*Drawbacks:*

- This approach does not use the same property name for same information represented differently. This *might* cause some difficulties for property matching, deserialization at client side.
- If the default view is still used somewhere for `Category`, it will contain both the field and the property accessed via the additional getter.
- Redundant and repetitive annotations :) harder to maintain.
- Redundant getter for `children` field.

Comment: I tried this idea, and it has serious drawback - when `jsonGenerator.writeObject()` is called the context is lost and new fresh `SerializerProvider` is constructed that is not aware of active view. As a result, only first level of the tree is rendered and deeper levels fall into the other branch. There should be `DefaultSerializerProvider` used explicitly (somehow), I'm still trying to find out exact way.

Comment: Nice remark, it made me rethink the approach. I've updated the answer.